# How can I move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head) & Undo commits

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset, git-revert, git-reflog

In Git, I was trying to do a `squash commit` by merging in another branch and then resetting `HEAD` to the previous place via:

```
git reset origin/master
```

But I need to step out of this. How can I move HEAD back to the previous location?

I have the SHA-1 fragment (`23b6772`) of the commit that I need to move it to. How can I get back to this commit?

Comment: HEAD is just a pointer to your current location (or revision to be precise). `git checkout 23b6772` should do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revert Git repo to a previous commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin No it should *not*. Checking out a commit directly *is* the reason detached HEAD state happened (since remote-tracking branches can't be checked out themselves and automatically defer to the commit they point to when you try to do so like OP did) Also, sorry for the necromantic comment :-) I sort of *hope* the initial problem is solved already...

Answer (score 697, accepted):

Before answering, let's add some background, explaining what this `HEAD` is.

## ***`First of all what is HEAD?`***

`HEAD` is simply a reference to the current commit (latest) on the current branch. 
There can only be a single `HEAD` at any given time (excluding `git worktree`).

The content of `HEAD` is stored inside `.git/HEAD` and it contains the 40 bytes SHA-1 of the current commit.

---

## ***`detached HEAD`***

If you are not on the latest commit - meaning that `HEAD` is pointing to a prior commit in history it's called ***`detached HEAD`***.

[image]

On the command line, it will look like this - SHA-1 instead of the branch name since the `HEAD` is not pointing to the tip of the current branch:

[image]

[image]

---

#### A few options on how to recover from a detached HEAD:

---

#### [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits to go back
```

This will checkout the new branch pointing to the desired commit. 
This command will checkout to a given commit. 
At this point, you can create a branch and start to work from this point on.

```
# Checkout a given commit.
# Doing so will result in a `detached HEAD` which mean that the `HEAD`
# is not pointing to the latest so you will need to checkout branch
# in order to be able to update the code.
git checkout <commit-id>

# Create a new branch forked to the given commit
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You can always use the `reflog` as well. 
`git reflog`  will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

#### ***[`git reset --hard <commit_id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)***

"Move" your HEAD back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt)) you can also use the `git rebase --no-autostash` as well.

[image]

---

#### ***[`git revert <sha-1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)***

"Undo" the given commit or commit range. 
The revert command will "undo" any changes made in the given commit. 
A new commit with the undo patch will be committed while the original commit will remain in history as well.

```sh
# Add a new commit with the undo of the original one.
# The <sha-1> can be any commit(s) or commit range
git revert <sha-1>
```

---

This schema illustrates which command does what. 
As you can see there, `reset && checkout` modify the `HEAD`.

[image]

Comment: *If you are not on the latest commit - meaning that HEAD is pointing to a prior commit in history its called detached HEAD* unless that prior commit in history is the tip of a different branch. In my experience, you could say that you are detached if HEAD is not pointing to a commit that is also pointed to by any branch. This does not apply for tags.

Comment: You can be in detached HEAD and on the same time have a branch with the same commit as the HEAD of this branch. I dont understand your comment

Comment: `git reset <commit>` from a **detached head** did not work for me. That's what I tried: I created an empty repo, added a file and committed 4 changes to it in order to create the master branch as seen in your top picture. Then I switched to commit #2 in order to get into "detached head" state. Then I issued `git reset [--hard | --soft] <commit #3>`. Now HEAD points to commit #3 and master (.git/refs/heads/master) still points to the tip of the branch (== commit #4). In other words, I'm still in "detached head" state. Why is this?

Comment: If you wish you can move to chat and i can try to resolve it with you

Answer (score 69):

First [`reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) locally:

```
git reset 23b6772
```

To see if you're on the right position, verify with:

```
git status
```

You will see something like:

> On branch master Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 17 commits,
> and can be fast-forwarded.

Then rewrite history *on your remote tracking branch* to reflect the change:

```
git push --force-with-lease // a useful command @oktober mentions in comments
```

Using [`--force-with-lease`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force-with-leaseltrefnamegt) instead of [`--force`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force) will raise an error if others have meanwhile committed to the remote branch, in which case you should fetch first. [More info in this article](http://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-push-force-with-lease).

Comment: Be EXCEEDINGLY CAUTIOUS with `git push --force`. In many situations it will make you the least popular person on the team for a little while....

Comment: to add to the above note, I just came across this quote at https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/ and had to add it: "A single git push --force command can easily ruin the day for a lot of people: [186 Jenkins] repositories have their branch heads rewinded to point to older commits, and in effect the newer commits were misplaced after the bad git-push." --very unpopular developer....

Comment: thank you! this helped me un-do a bad merge. since merges don't react the same way to `revert` as commits I found myself in an incredibly difficult situation. `force-with-lease` gave me the confidence to rewrite the git history of the branch without affecting other people's work. bravo!

Answer (score 26):

## Quickest possible solution (just 1 step)

Use `git checkout -`

You will see `Switched to branch <branch_name>`. Confirm it's the branch you want.

---

Brief explanation: this command will move HEAD back to its last position. See note on **outcomes** at the end of this answer.

---

Mnemonic: this approach is a lot like using `cd -` to return to your previously visited directory. Syntax and the applicable cases are a pretty good match (e.g. it's useful when you actually want HEAD to return to where it was).

---

## More methodical solution (2-steps, but memorable)

The quick approach solves the OP's question. But what if your situation is slightly different: say you have restarted Bash then found yourself with HEAD detached. In that case, here are 2 simple, easily remembered steps.

### 1. Pick the branch you need

Use `git branch -v`

You see a list of existing local branches. Grab the branch name that suits your needs.

### 2. Move HEAD to it

Use `git checkout <branch_name>`

You will see `Switched to branch <branch_name>`. Success!

---

### Outcomes

With either method, you can now continue adding and committing your work as before: your next changes will be tracked on `<branch_name>`.

Note that both `git checkout -` and `git checkout <branch_name>` will give additional instructions if you have committed changes while HEAD was detached.

Comment: This is not working because if I do (assuming that 8acc968 is HEAD~2)
`git checkout 8acc968`then `git branch -v` has `MyBranch` in the list below 
...but then `git checkout MyBranch` deletes my comments.

Comment: Hi @amuliar - ```git checkout 8acc968``` will check out a commit, not a branch. If ```MyBranch``` has the commits you want, try ```git checkout MyBranch```. If it does not contain the changes in commit 8acc968, you would need to merge those changes after checking out the branch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did `git checkout` to see a previous commit and wanted to get back to the latest commit. But without the latest commit hash, I was pretty much lost. This solution is perfect for my situation!

Comment: `git checkout -` does not necessarily have the effect you say.

Answer (score 8):

The question can be read as:

***I was in detached-state with `HEAD` at `23b6772` and typed `git reset origin/master` (because I wanted to squash). Now I've changed my mind, how do I go back to `HEAD` being at `23b6772`?***

The straightforward answer being: `git reset 23b6772`

But I hit this question because I got sick of typing (copy & pasting) commit hashes or its abbreviation each time I wanted to reference the previous `HEAD` and was Googling to see if there were any kind of shorthand.

### It turns out there is!

`git reset -` (or in my case `git cherry-pick -`)

Which incidentally was the same as `cd -` to return to the previous *current directory* in *nix! So hurrah, I learned two things with one stone.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command `git checkout commit_id` then HEAD detached from `13ca5593d(say commit-id)` and branch will be on longer available.

Move back to previous location run the command step wise -

1. `git pull origin branch_name` (say master)
2. `git checkout branch_name`
3. `git pull origin branch_name`

You will be back to the previous location with an updated commit from the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I mistakenly checked out on a commit and started working on it, making some commits on a detach HEAD state. Then I pushed to the remote branch using the following command:

```
git push origin HEAD: <My-remote-branch>
```

Then

```
git checkout <My-remote-branch>
```

Then

```
git pull
```

I finally got my all changes in my branch that I made in detach HEAD.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a technical solution, but it works. (if anyone of your teammate has the same branch in local)

Let's assume your branch name as **branch-xxx**.

Steps to Solve:

- Don't do update or pull - nothing
- Just create a new branch (**branch-yyy**) from **branch-xxx** on his machine
- That's all, all your existing changes will be in this new branch (**branch-yyy**). You can continue your work with this branch.

Note: Again, this is not a technical solution, but it will help for sure.

Answer (score 0):

## Move last non-pushed commits to a new branch

If your problem is that you started committing on the WRONG_BRANCH, and want to move those last non-pushed commits to the RIGHT_BRANCH, the easiest thing to do is

1. `git checkout WRONG_BRANCH`
2. `git branch RIGHT_BRANCH`
3. `git reset —-hard LAST_PUSHED_COMMIT`
4. `git checkout RIGHT_BRANCH`

At this point, if you run `git log HEAD` you will see that all your commits are there, in the RIGHT_BRACH.

### Data

- *WRONG_BRANCH* is where your committed changes (yet to push) are now
- *RIGHT_BRANCH* is where your committed changes (yet to push) will be
- *LAST_PUSHED_COMMIT* is where you want to restore the WRONG_BRANCH to